# Toyota aygo engine oil 0W-20 or 5W-30?

Tags: toyota, oil

What is the correct engine oil type to use with a Toyota Aygo 2007 1.0 VVT-i?
[Toyoa](https://www.toyota.co.uk/owners/service-mot-maintenance/oil) says it should be 0W-20, while [halfords](https://www.halfords.com/motoring/engine-oils-fluids/engine-oil) and [mobil](https://lubes.mobil.com/UK-English-LCW/carengineoils_which-oil.aspx) says it should be 5W-30. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, Toyota make it and Halfrauds know more... Or is the choice of oil location dependant?

Comment: Your location is likely important for your oil choice. Does your owners manual recommend a higher weight oil for higher temperatures or heavier loads?

Comment: I haven't got the manual unfortunately. The car is in UK though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit strange, as I wouldn't expect a big oil company like Mobil to get the recommended oil incorrect, but even stranger is the fact that Toyota's site doesn't let you choose anything older than 2009...

Among the online references, I would stick to Toyota's recommendation (because it's the same generation with the same engine). However, an even more reliable method would be to check your **physical owner's manual**, or if you don't have it, there is a good chance your **oil fill cap** will list the recommended oil for your car.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the manual but I'll have a look at the oil fill cap tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure if these numbers mean anything but inside the oil fill cap it says `(some symbol)-18-6   >PA6<   5`.

Comment: Normally, owners manuals are available for download online... but no matter how hard I tried, I couldn't get one from any of Toyota's utterly obtuse websites. Here's the best one I've got, it's for a newer model, but it still has the same 1KR-FE engine (page 409): https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1218300/Toyota-Aygo.html?page=409#manual It looks correct, but trust this source at your own risk.

Comment: Oil grade: **0W-20, 5W-20, 5W-30 and 10W-30**: API grade SL "Energy-Conserving", SM "Energy-Conserving" or SN "Resource-Conserving"; or ILSAC multigrade engine oil. **SAE 0W-20 is filled into your Toyota vehicle at manufacturing, and the best choice for good fuel economy and good starting in cold weather.** If SAE 0W-20 oil is not available, SAE 5W-30 oil may be used. However, it should be replaced with SAE 0W-20 at the next oil change.